# How to specify #define commands for my two different targets

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, target

I have a project I am splitting into two targets.  The original single-target project uses a number of define commands, however I need these values to now be different depending on which target I am building.

What's the correct way to do that?  Should I be using NStrings declared on the AppDelegate?  Or can I use a #if statement when settings the #defines?

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be like this:

```
#if defined(MON_TARGET_A)
  #define MON_TARGET_NAME "App A"
#elif defined(MON_TARGET_B)
  #define MON_TARGET_NAME "App B"
#else
  #error "which target are you building?"
#endif
```

Then add `MON_TARGET_A` or `MON_TARGET_B` to your target's preprocessor settings.

Usually, you'll use `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS` and not `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` because the latter can prevent sharing of PCH headers.

To add this, go to:

- Project Navigator -> Project -> Target -> Build Settings

then drop `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS` into the search field and set its value to something like: `MON_TARGET_A $(inherited)`

Comment: Why the MON_... prefix, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @NickLockwood it's silly - you know how some people write their examples: `MyClass`? I use `MON` instead of `My` (e.g. `MONClass`) for examples. french twist. (en:my == fr:mon)

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional preprocessor macros in your target settings (Preprocessing->Preprocessor Macros) and use #ifdef.

This is the most flexible approach.

Comment: Max!  You were spot on, but Justin got there first. Thanks anyway sir!